# How to add parameter to url in all request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem. I have request e.g. http://site.pl/site.aspx?data=value
in frist use in session I save property data in session. I can't use a cookies. I have a problem when session is expire. maybe possible to automatically add this parameter to user url in hiperlinks?

Comment: If you're using session, you're _already_ using cookies.

Comment: @SLaks he could be using cookieless session (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Comment: @Gonzix not with that url he isnt

Comment: Do you mean you need to add "data=value" to all links displayed on the page? If so, you can read it directly from Request and add to the links during page rendering (might need to do some sanitizing to avoid XSS)

Comment: It's hard to determine if he intended to say he can't use a cookie to save that variable or can't use cookies in general...

"I can't use a cookies".  Did he mean to say he can't use "a cookie" or "can't use cookies".

Comment: @NicholasKing touche!